# How can I set response header on express.js assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to set CORS to be enabled on scripts served by express. How can I set the headers in these returned responses for public/assets?

Answer (score 533, accepted):

There is at least one middleware on npm for handling CORS in Express: [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). [see @mscdex answer]

This is how to set custom response headers, from the [ExpressJS DOC](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set)

```
res.set(field, [value])
```

Set header field to value

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

or pass an object to set multiple fields at once.

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '12345'
})
```

Aliased as

```
res.header(field, [value])
```

Comment: How can I get these values? Because I set these values in `res` object. When I try to see this content I go undefined using `res.headers`;

Comment: Then I use `res.write('content')`?

Comment: This line be should be used before writing the head.

Comment: For some reason `res.set` didn't work for me, but the `cors` middleware did the trick just right.

Comment: @BrunoCasali extra headers are blocked by browser by default, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931084/1507207

Answer (score 108):

This is so annoying.

Okay if anyone is still having issues or just doesn't want to add another library. All you have to do is place this middle ware line of code before your routes.

> Cors Example

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});

// Express routes
app.get('/api/examples', (req, res)=> {...});
```

Comment: Important this point relative to the order. I was wondering if really it was important as I saw different behaviours when changing it. Nice. Thanks

Comment: Nice: solved the problem perfectly. Adding an entire dependency to perform these 6 lines of code is not a road that I would recommend for anyone...

Answer (score 23):

**Short Answer:**

- `res.setHeaders` - calls the native Node.js method
- `res.set` - sets headers
- `res.headers` - an alias to res.set

Answer (score 17):

You can do this by using cors. cors will handle your CORS response

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 15):

@klode's answer is right.

However, you are supposed to set another response header to make your header accessible to others.

---

Example:

First, you add 'page-size' in response header

```
response.set('page-size', 20);
```

Then, all you need to do is expose your header

```
response.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'page-size')
```

Comment: I was stuck for over an hour trying to figure out why none of my custom headers were making it to the other end. Exposing them was the answer. Thank you so much! Why this header has zero mention in the Express docs (or in any articles I've read thus far about custom headers) is very puzzling.

Comment: What if you had 2 headers?
Like this:
```javascript
res.set("...","...");
res.set("...","....");
```
Now how do you expose those 2 headers?

Comment: I discovered how reading the docs:
```javascript
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
// or
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: <header-name>, <header-name>, ...
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
service.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

There is at least one middleware on npm for handling CORS in Express: [cors](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors).

Answer (score 9):

You can also add a middleware to add CORS headers, something like this would work:

```
/**
 * Adds CORS headers to the response
 *
 * {@link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing}
 * {@link http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set}
 * @param {object} request the Request object
 * @param {object} response the Response object
 * @param {function} next function to continue execution
 * @returns {void}
 * @example
 * <code>
 * const express = require('express');
 * const corsHeaders = require('./middleware/cors-headers');
 *
 * const app = express();
 * app.use(corsHeaders);
 * </code>
 */
module.exports = (request, response, next) => {
    // http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set
    response.set({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE,GET,PATCH,POST,PUT',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization'
    });

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if(request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        response.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

First add 'field' in response header

```
response.set('field', 'value');
```

Then you need to do is expose your header

```
response.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'field')
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of the express.js 4.18.2:

If you are using `static` middleware, and want to change the response header, you should:

```
app.use(express.static('./', {
  setHeaders: function(res) {
    res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, I have tested those three methods , and they all work:

```
    res.header('env', process.env.ENV);
    res.setHeader('env', process.env.ENV);
    res.set('env', process.env.ENV);
```