# Node.js express response not returning the content type

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new at Node.js and I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqMIyTH9wSg). Everything is doing fine, except when I try to return a json object, like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    users: ["Will", "Laura2"]
  });
});
```

The browser shows me the "users" object as a "document" type, not as an application/json type. The same occours to any type (status code, text/plain, and so on).

[image: "document" type instead "application/json"]

The rest of my code is exactly like the code in the tutorial.

```
├── body-parser@1.13.3
├── cookie-parser@1.3.5
├── debug@2.2.0
├── express@4.13.3
├── hjs@0.0.6
├── less-middleware@1.0.4
├── morgan@1.6.1
└── serve-favicon@2.3.0

npm 2.14.7
node v4.2.2
```

**EDIT: Here is my app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
//app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**EDIT: here is my index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
//router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
//});


router.get('/', function(req, res) {    
  res.send({
    users: ["Will", "Laura"]
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

It looks like the "application/json" type is not being accepted, so the browser shows the content as a "document" type. See the following image:

[image: browser console]

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Since both `res.send`, `res.json` and `res.set` doesn't work for you, the obvious conclusion is that you're **overwriting** the content type somewhere else.

Look at your middlewares, those that are after your `router.get`. See if any of them do anything to `res`.
Also, can you add the initialization of `router`?

---

Look here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send

I don't think it's added by default, no matter if you're using `.send` or `.json`, as the docs don't mention adding an appropriate `Content Type` header.

**From the `.json` docs:**

> Sends a JSON response. This method is identical to res.send() with an object or array as the parameter.

However, you can do it like so:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send({
    users: ["Will", "Laura2"]
  });
});
```

Comment: res.json() not working. Adding res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); neither

Comment: Well then you must be overwriting the `Content Type` somewhere.

Comment: I'll do some googling soon, let's get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
res.json({
    users: ["Will", "Laura2"]
  });
```

to respond with JSON body

You can set content-type header using the syntax, which is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759686/2159867)

**EDIT**:
try sending the request using HTTP/REST extensions like POSTMAN or REST Client you can get the application/json response header

Comment: I tried, but I'm getting the same result: a "document" type.

Comment: you can then explicitly set header res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: Adding res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); did not work

Comment: try res.header('content-type', 'application/json'),

Comment: are you using any other middleware?

Comment: No. As I said, I'm following the tutorial of my question from scratch

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    users: ["Will", "Laura2"]
  });
});
```

Just replace 'send' with 'json' and it will work...
And for returning status code also, you can use under below...

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    users: ["Will", "Laura2"]
  });
});
```