# node.js/express: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httpresponse, response-headers

Despite there being a ton of stackoverflow questions and articles online about this topic, none seem to apply to my particular application.

```
router.get('/getFile', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Calling getFile for file " + req.query.serialNumber + ".")
    var serialNumber = req.query.serialNumber;
    let request = new sql.Request(conn);
    request.query('SELECT FileName + \'.\' + FileExtension AS \'File\', FileType, ContentType, SerialNumber, Chart ' +
        'FROM dbo.ChangeFiles ' +
        'WHERE SerialNumber = ' + serialNumber)
        .then(function (recordset) {
            log("Successfully retrieved file " + recordset[0].SerialNumber + " from database.")
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': recordset[0].ContentType,
                'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + recordset[0].File
            });
            res.send(Buffer(recordset[0].Chart));
        }).catch(function (err) {
            log(err);
            res.send("Issue querying database!");
        });
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to properly change the headers so that it is done before res.send hits.  It is most likely due to the asynchronous nature of javascript, something I still have yet to grasp properly, but how can I ensure that res.writeHead is called before res.send?

Thank you so much in advance for looking at this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set response header on express.js assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751914/how-can-i-set-response-header-on-express-js-assets)

Comment: Does using res.end instead of res.send work?

Comment: use res.setHeader() along with res.status() and res.send()

Comment: Thank you for all of the quick responses guys, I will be looking at all of this tomorrow morning when I get back to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `res.writeHead()` the headers are immediately sent to the requester. Since you're using the Express function `res.send()`, [which also sends over your headers](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send), they have already been sent and you will get an error saying the headers have already been sent. Alternatively, you could use [`res.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) which will not cause a headers sent error since it will finalize the response and send whatever remaining chunks are passed to it.

> how can I ensure that res.writeHead is called before res.send?

If you're going to use `res.send()`, change your `res.writeHead()` calls to `res.setHeader()` to set the header values on your response object. Additionally, when using Express you can set the `status` of the response using `res.status(<statusCode>)`.

Another thing I noticed is you usage of `Buffer`. You should change your `Buffer` creation in the success response handler from `Buffer()` to `Buffer.from()` as `Buffer()` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array).

```
router.get('/getFile', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Calling getFile for file " + req.query.serialNumber + ".")

    let serialNumber = req.query.serialNumber
    let request = new sql.Request(conn)
    let query = 'SELECT FileName + \'.\' + FileExtension AS \'File\', FileType, ContentType, SerialNumber, Chart ' +
        'FROM dbo.ChangeFiles ' +
        'WHERE SerialNumber = ' + serialNumber

    request.query(query)
        .then(recordset =>{
            console.log("Successfully retrieved file " + recordset[0].SerialNumber + " from database.")

            let {ContentType, Chart File} = recordset[0]

            // Set Response Status and Headers
            res.status(200)
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', ContentType)
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment;filename=${File}`)            

            return res.send(Buffer.from(Chart))
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send("Issue querying database!");
        })
})
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully.  Thank you so much!  As for the downvote, who knows.  StackOverflow loves the stealth downvoting.