# Cannot set headers for Express.js app (CORS)

Tags: node.js, express, cors

No matter what I try to use to set the headers it simply won't work.

The server side needs to send the response headers like this, after accepting the `POST` request from Frontend.

`server.js`

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
   res.set({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
   });
   res.send('string');
   res.end();
}
```

The `res.set()` function was not the only function I tried to use.

I tried with:

`res.writeHead(201, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})` - doesn't work

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` - nope

`res.headers()` - also doesn't work

It says here that it goes like this: [How can I set response header on express.js assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751914/how-can-i-set-response-header-on-express-js-assets) but the answer doesn't work for me.

No matter what I tried, the server just won't respond with the CORS enabled header and I need that header property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you testing the resource with? When using a browser keep in mind that on a cross-origin POST request the browser will first send a preflight request which needs to be handled properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the cors module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var cors = require('cors')

...

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: This is the solution. I'm trying to use less and less modules as I want to write vanilla Node.js apps, but headers in Express (when it comes to headers) simply doesn't want to work the way I imagined. Thank you, now everything is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** response header indicates which headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

```
res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, <any-other-custom-header>, ...');
```