# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' / 500 (Internal Server Error) Problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sequelize.js, body-parser

Basically, I'm trying to get a username by id from Sequelize. The problem is that I am either stuck with a CORS problem or 500 Internal Server error depending on the response(status)

[cors and 500](https://i.gyazo.com/07a6e582677b2b7fe149ecf2c99552d9.png)

## controller code

```
    async getUserFromUserId (req, res) {
        try {
            // const user = await User.findByPk(req.body.id)
            const id = req.body.id
            const user = await User.findByPk(id)
            res.send(user.username)
            } catch (err) {

            // or res.status(some random number).send() for CORS problem to appear

            res.status(500).send({
                error: 'an error has occured trying to fetch the users id'
            })
        }
    },
```

## client code

```
this.notifiedUser = (await UserService.getUserFromUserId({id: UserId})).data
```

I get a Status: 200 OK from postman though.
[Postman Solution](https://i.gyazo.com/9757cc1df78417d7cbefb2e0a23211b7.png)

Edit:
I have seen how the other [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present) for the cors thingy, but the solutions does not specify as to why I get "undefined" results after resolving the cors problem.

Comment: Postman is not cors restricted like browsers are. Implement cors middleware server side

Comment: wow the simplicity of ur explanation actually helps a ton, rather than looking at all the other related cors problem that is explained in a multitude of words. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out the problem.
In a way, I did not have to deal with any of the cors stuff because I believe that was not the main source of the problem.

So, instead of accessing my database data through "GET" and getting the data by doing this:

```
this.data = (Service.function(bodyValue)).data
```

I did "POST" to get the data, and accessed the data by simply doing this

```
const response = Service.function({
                    id: bodyValue
                })
this.data = response.data
```

This accesses the data without having to get "secured" information from the database, but by accessing the data from the database by getting **Observer** object info from the database.

The **Observer** object looks as [follows](https://i.gyazo.com/2c866acd9ce688a01a75adf580599b51.png), which treats the user data as an object instead of pure data.

Compared to a data [object](https://i.gyazo.com/52b179bd6c22a7f03f6886d92599415f.png), where each data {...} has user information.

I am not sure if I am using the correct words, but these are to the extent of my current understanding.

Answer (score 4):

So, CORS is actually really obnoxious in this regard, but there's a fairly straightforward way to fix this. It's a super useful security feature, though it is frustrating at best sometimes.

Your browser does what is called a Preflight Request, which is of the http verb `OPTIONS`. Your browser calls whatever route you want, but instead of what you asked it to do, it calls using `OPTIONS` first. Your server should accept all routes that the client can ask for with the `OPTIONS` method, and your server should respond with the following headers to be an externally available, cross-origin API.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, ...
```

(note, you should not put the ... in, but you can put any HTTP verb in this list)

If you require your own headers (for auth purposes), you want to add this header for Client -> Server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: YourHeader, YourHeader2, YourHeader3
```

You want to add this one for Server -> Client

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: YourHeader,YourHeader3
```

Note that the `OPTIONS` call is an entirely separate call that you should handle as well as the `GET` method.

You've now told the browser what it is allowed to ask for, and what it can expect to get back from your API. If you don't respond to the `OPTIONS` request, the browser terminates the request, resulting in a CORS error.

I'm going to take a gander at a guess and assume you're likely using Express, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751914/how-can-i-set-response-header-on-express-js-assets) describes how to set the headers on.

### What do the headers mean, in English?

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
From where are clients allowed to access this resource (endpoint)? This can match partial domains with wildcards, or just a `*` to allow anywhere.

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`
What HTTP methods are permissible on this route?

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`
When I get a response from the server, what should I (the browser) expose to the client-side?

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`
What am I as the client side allowed to send as headers?

Comment: correct, I am using express.
so instead I just did this:

var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors()).

So I believe this handles creating middleware for handling CORS through Express.
The problem though now is, I am getting "undefined" as a result of my res.send(user.username).

Comment: Splendid! That means you're halfway there. At the link at the end of this comment, scroll down and find the section that says `Enabling CORS Pre-Flight`, and examine how it responds to the `options` request.

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @charlietfl That's true, it should. If it were doing so, he wouldn't be running into CORS errors though, as they'd have been resolved by the middleware. I find CORS is one of those technologies that are super important to understand, and there aren't many good explanations of what is going on behind the scenes with CORS.

Comment: hey thanks a lot man for helping out! i'll later try to do what you're asking and I'll see how it goes

Answer (score -3):

If your origin is from localhost, Chrome usually blocks any CORS request originating from this origin.

You can install this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Or you can disable the security when running chrome (add the flag):

--disable-web-security

Comment: I use cors in localhost all the time with no issues

Comment: I have done this, now the result is "undefined". is there a way to fix this?, what is the problem occuring now? thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Localhost isn't in any way special when it comes to CORS. The request is cross-origin if the domain, protocol or port doesn't match, and that's it.