# create-react-app Server + Node Server Without XSS Problems?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I'm using a `create-react-app`-generated server for my front-end (under the hood it uses Webpack's dev server), and I'm using Node/Express for back-end.  Whenever I have this combination, I always run into XSS issues (eg. between `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4000`) because the two servers have to run on different ports.

Given that my production site will be serving everything from the same domain, I don't really *need* CORS or anything fancy.  Is there any sort of easy/hack way to avoid cross-domain issues in such a local dev environment?

Comment: You can set the response header  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*" in the express server. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751914/how-can-i-set-response-header-on-express-js-assets) might help

Comment: In dev it's possible to setup Express as a reverse proxy for webpac-dev-server so that your React app doesn't know that script bundles are fetched from webpack-dev-server nor does it know webpack-dev-server exists. Therefore you have no CORS issues because everything comes from one source: Express. Similar arrangement for production, the only difference is that Express should serve webpack build artifacts (bundles etc.) from disk and not from webpack-dev-server because the latter is not really meant to be used in production. If you are ok with Typescript I can provide an example.

Comment: Those are both great answers (though @nithin's suggestion sounds easiest).  But I can't upvote and/or accept either one in the form of a comment, so please provide those as answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*" in the express server. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751914/how-can-i-set-response-header-on-express-js-assets) might help.