# React.js - Modify response

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to remove / modify my react.js's response headers.

I want to for example remove the header "X-Powered-By".

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: I want to do this in REACT.JS, not express.

Comment: React is a frontend framework, it's not setting any headers. Are you talking about headers set by the `create-react-app` dev server?

Comment: Yes, and production.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `create-react-app` dev server for production, it's not secure or optimised. Regardless, I don't think the dev server exposes the kind of customisation you want, as it's simply not intended for that.

Comment: How would i do it in production?

Comment: You'd use a different web server, such as express or nginx, and refer to @jperl's answer about the former. If you have some idea of where you're deploying then that may influence your decision about which web server to use.

Comment: So you would setup your react.js with express? Whats the point in react-router then

Comment: They are completely different things. Express is a web server, it is used to (among other things) serve static files such as `index.html` and `foo.js`. `react-router` is a library used within the React single page app to simulate browser navigation without making any further file requests to your web server. You use a web server like express to send your app to the client, then the app runs and `react-router` says "Oh, you're looking for the route `/foo`? I happen to know that means you want component `Foo`, I'll load it for you."

Comment: Yea i know, but you're telling me you can't modify headers in react.js - So I'm asking what's the point of doing react routering if you're gonna set it up with express?

Comment: The only thing that express serves is the static files, those have headers. In-app navigation is handled by `react-router` and no further requests for static files are made, and therefore there are no headers on in-app navigations.

Answer (score 0):

`React.JS` as such does not generate any `HTTP headers`. `HTTP headers` may be added by your web server or possibly by a `REST` client library such as `Axios`. Please share more information on your setup.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling Express's default X-Powered-By is as easy as:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

See

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.disable

If you want to modify headers:

```
..., function(req, res) {
  ...
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  ...
}
```

Your question already has an answer here: [How can I set response header on express.js assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751914/how-can-i-set-response-header-on-express-js-assets)

Comment: I know, but that's not what im asking for.

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Hobey823 I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: The OP question is about React.js, not express

Comment: it still doesn't answering the question

Comment: @mthrsj The question "How do I remove headers from react js" is not really answerable, jperl made the most reasonable guess and answered accordingly.

Comment: @mthrsj if you know how to set headers for reactjs (which makes no sense to me), be my guest!

Comment: You should've answered that instead @jperl, since that would've been helpful.

Comment: Sorry, it was a misunderstanding. At first, there were an express + a nodejs tags, so I took a guess. React is not a web server.