# How to send session ID in header via post request method

Tags: javascript

Is this possible to send session ID in header via post request

Here is my code in express JS :

```
app.use(session({

secret: 'newsession',

saveUninitialized:false,

resave:false,

cookie: {

    secure: false,

    httpOnly:false,


}}));


app.post ('/login', function (request, response, next) {

const { username  , password } = request.body

db.find(db.COLLECTIONS.USERS,{username: username, password: password}).then((users) => {

    if (users.length !== 0) {
        request.session.isAuth=true;
        response.status(200).json(users[0]);
    } else {

        response.status(409).send("Username not found");
    }
}).catch(() => {
    response.status(409).send();
});
```

});

now when I am going send post request in postman using JSON type for example:

```
  {

 "username":"user",
 "password":"user"

  }
```

I want to know is it possible to send  session id in header to client from server ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759686 on how to set a response header using express.js

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you want to perform. Anything you can send in headers via below syntax

```
res.set(field, [value])
```

or

```
res.header(field, [value])
```

Ex:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

or

```
res.header('sessionId', 'yourId');
```